# What does the "comma operator" $(v,w)$ mean when $v$ and $w$ are vectors?

Tags: vectors

I came across this equation for a line-cylinder intersection but I am only familiar with the dot and cross products...

$$(q - p_a - (v_a, q - p_a)v_a)^2 - r^2 = 0$$

My assumptions:

- $$(q - p_a - (v_a, q - p_a)v_a)^2$$ corresponds to a dot product
- $$(v_a, q - p_a)v_a$$ corresponds to a cross product
- $$v_a, q - p_a$$ some sort of comma product

all of these assumptions may be wrong however, would really appreciate someone explaining what this notation means.

source: [Cylinder-ray intersections equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406446/cylinder-ray-intersections-equation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this (frankly, absurd) notation is the inner product:

$$(v_a,q-p_a) = \langle v_a, q-p_a\rangle = v_a\cdot (q-p_a).$$

I don't see any part of the expression where a cross product would make sense.

It also looks like this expression uses a second (more common) abuse of notation by writing $v^2$ for $\|v\|^2$.

Comment: Saw your answer right after submitting mine, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like an unusual notation for a dot product.  That is, $(\vec u, \vec v)$ is being used to mean $\vec u \bullet \vec v$.  Seems like it may be inspired by the notation for the inner product of two vectors (a generalization of the dot product from Euclidean spaces to more general vector spaces) which is typically denoted $\langle \vec u, \vec v \rangle$.